# the minimal diameter of a quadrilateral 

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Let a convex quadrilateral ABCD with perimeter 1，d is the maximum of AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD,prove that d is not less than 1/3
  we can prove that parallelogram ABCD with perimeter 1，than one of AC,BD is more than 1/3
  but the general case is very difficult to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer given by ε-δ (a kite inscribed in a Reuleaux triangle) can be found in

Ball, D. G. (1973), "A generalisation of π", *Mathematical Gazette* 57 (402): 298–303, doi:[10.2307/3616052](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%252F3616052), JSTOR [3616052](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3616052);

He doesn't give an explicit proof that this is optimal but says it can be done by "some tedious but not very difficult trigonometry. See also

Griffiths, David; Culpin, David (1975), "Pi-optimal polygons", *Mathematical Gazette* 59 (409): 165–175, doi:[10.2307/3617699](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%252F3617699), JSTOR [3617699](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3617699)

for extensions to higher order polygons.

Answer (score 6):

[Quadrilateral Image http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/rgwvd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/rgwvd.png)

It is not true.

Take $A=0$, $B=1$, $C=e^{\frac\pi6 i}$ $D=e^{\frac\pi3 i}$.
Then $d=1$ and the perimeter is $2+\tfrac1{\cos\frac{\pi}{12}} >3$.

I am sure that $\frac1{2+\tfrac1{\cos\frac{\pi}{12}}}$ is the optimal bound.

Comment: How is this convex?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.09

Comment: it is convex, $A$, $B$ and $D$ are vertices of equilateral triangle and $C$ is on the extension of the bisector at $A$.

Comment: OK.  For some reason C kept appearing (to me) on the inside of triangle ABD.  Gerhard "Not Enough Coffee This Morning" Paseman, 2012.01.09

Comment: $|e^{ix}|\equiv 1$, it can not be inside...

Comment: (I fixed the image URL...)

Comment: OK!,But how to prove that $\frac1{2+\tfrac1{\cos\frac{\pi}{12}}}$ is the optimal bound.
